# expr: нецелочисленный аргумент

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash

function koiwin
{
num="$(cat $1)"
for i in ${num[*]}
do
  low=$low"\3$i"
  up=$up"\3`expr $i + 40`"
done
echo $up$low
return
}


if test $# -lt 3
  then echo "Usage: `basename $0` tablica.txt input.win output.koi"
  exit 7
fi

if ! test -f $2                    # Проверка существования входного файла
  then echo "$2: No such regular file" >&2
  exit 2
fi


if ! test -r $2                    # Контроль доступа чтения для входного файла
  then echo "$2: Permission denied to read" >&2
  exit 13
fi

# Контроль маршрутного имени для выходного файла
curdir=`pwd`
outdir=`expr $3 : '\(.*/\)' \| $curdir`


if [ ! -w $outdir -a ! -e $3 ]    # Контроль каталога по (пере)записи
  then echo "$outdir: Permission denied to write" >&2
  exit -13
fi


if test -d $3                     # Проверка, что выходной файл не каталог
  then echo "$3: Is directory" >&2
  exit 21
fi


if [ -e $3 -a ! -w $3 ]           # Контроль перезаписи выходного файла
  then echo $3: Permission denied to rewrite
  exit 13
fi


if [ -f $3 ]
  then while [ 1 > 0 ]
    do echo "$2 already exists. Would you like to rewrite it? (y/n)"
    read ans
    if [ "$ans" == "n" ]
        then exit 1
    elif [ "$ans" == "y" ]
        then cat $2 | tr `koiwin` "\300-\337\340-\377" > $3
        exit 0
    else
        echo "Error"
        exit 1
    fi
  done
fi


cat $2 | tr `koiwin` "\300-\337\340-\377" > $3
```

После запуска:

```
./koiwin.sh table.txt sometext.koi sometext.win
expr: нецелочисленный аргумент
expr: нецелочисленный аргумент
```

table.txt:

```
01 02 27 07 04 05 26 32 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 20 22 23 24 25 06 10 03 36 33 35 37 31 30 34 00 21
```

При этом тут все работает:

```
#! /bin/bash


num="$(cat $1)"
for i in ${num[*]}
do
  low=$low"\3$i"
  up=$up"\3`expr $i + 40`"
done
echo $up$low
```

Вывод:

```
./test.sh table.txt 
\341\342\367\347\344\345\366\372\351\352\353\354\355\356\357\360\362\363\364\365\346\350\343\376\373\375\377\371\370\374\340\361\301\302\327\307\304\305\326\332\311\312\313\314\315\316\317\320\322\323\324\325\306\310\303\336\333\335\337\331\330\334\300\321
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это распротраненная ошибка. Вы путаете аргументы функции и аргументы скрипта. Вот простой пример:

```
$ cat test
#!/bin/bash

fun(){ echo "$1"; }

echo run fun
fun

echo args
echo "$1"

echo fun with args
fun "$1"
```

Попробуем запустить:

```
$ ./test test
run fun

args
test
fun with args
test
```

Функция без аргументов не вывела ничего, хотя скрипту передан аргумент "test". Дело в том что переменные типа $1,2,3... внутри функции не являются указателями аргументов скрипта, это указатели на аргументы переданные самой функции. Если вам нужно обработать информацию переданную через аргументы скрипта какой-либо функцией, вы должны передать соотв. аргумент в функцию, вот так:

```
fun(){ echo "$1"; }
fun "$1"
```

Либо создать переменные для аргументов скрипта и использовать их в функциях:

```
#!/bin/bash
arg1=$1
fun(){ echo "$arg1"; }
fun
```